# sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This DecisionTreeClassifier instance is not fitted yet

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

im try to visualize  decision tree with using mode from image data in python without graphviz using DecisionTreeClassifier but im keep getting error

sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: This DecisionTreeClassifier instance is not fitted yet. Call 'fit' with appropriate arguments before using this estimator.

even i try in google colab and VScode it still getting error. My dataset only have 2 columns is ModusH and Index.

Here my dataset examples
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K64Dy.jpg)

And Here the Code

```
datapisang= pd.read_csv('DataModusdiperbaiki.csv')           
X= datapisang[['ModusH']]                                    
Y= datapisang[['Index']]                                     
X_train, X_test, Y_train, Y_test = train_test_split(X, Y)    
# Model
DT_model= DecisionTreeClassifier()                            
DT_model.fit(X_train,Y_train)                               
DT_model.print_tree()                                       
data = [Modus_citra] # Mode Image                                        
hasilprediksi = DT_model.predict([data])                     

fn = ['ModusH'] 
cn = ['Index'] 

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows = 1,ncols = 1,figsize = (4,4), dpi=300)

tree.plot_tree(DT_model,
           feature_names = fn, 
           class_names=cn,
           filled = True);

fig.savefig('imagename.png')
```

Im try to get the visualize but it keep error everytime even using graphviz. Im new to this topic, can someone help me ?  i appreciate every help.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it as below, as shown in [documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.plot_tree.html)

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from sklearn import tree

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)
iris = load_iris()

clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

tree.plot_tree(clf)
```

### Based on edit:

I tried to regenerate your situation by creating a new dataframe; here is the solution:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100,size=(100, 1)), columns=["ModusH"])
df['Index'] = np.random.choice(  a=[0, 1, 2,3,4],size=df.shape[0])   

clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=0)

clf = clf.fit(df.ModusH.to_numpy().reshape(-1, 1), df.Index)

tree.plot_tree(clf)
```

Comment: ok this is work , but im  getting  error DecisionTreeClassifier.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'random_state.  My csv file only 2 column data,  so can be visualize ?

Comment: @DoniFidomen please update your question, either share your data or implement your solution with `iris` dataset to have a complete picture and helping you with the problem.

Comment: how do i share my dataset into stack ?

Comment: Do not share the whole dataset, share some samples like `pandas` dataframe. [pandas sharing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: i have share some example mydataset, it in the picture

Comment: witch one is index list ?  Because error list index out of range

Comment: And also witch one is X and Y ?

Comment: Also in my dataframe i have 5 categories in ModusH :  first one is immature (range 32 -60), second is half ripe (range 25-30), Third one is ripe (range 22- 24), fourth one is Very ripe (range 17 -19) , last one is rotten (Hue 8 -10) .  Can you help me with that ?

Comment: @DoniFidomen this example I mentioned is based on random data, you should customized based on your needs. If it is not clear I recommend you to reading some articles about basic of machine learning. Thanks :)